# C# standalone WebDAV

Tags: c#, .net, webdav

I'm seeing all these iPhone apps with built-in freestanding webDav servers.  Are there any freestanding (as in its own IIS) C# webDAV projects which can be integrated into existing applications.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627705/net-webdav-server

Comment: @M.Babcock things change over time, and that question is at over 2 year old.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp - So WebDAV is no longer the protocol it once was? Is the answer there any less valid?

Comment: @Babcock - No - I'd say WebDAV is still very much alive.  It's still the standard for web-based document authoring.  I think Eugene was commenting that the original question is old and there may have been innovations in the interceding years.

Answer (score 1):

There exist at least two commercial WebDAV servers for use in .NET. One by [IT Hit](http://www.webdavsystem.com/server) and another one is our [WebDAVBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-webdav.php) (part of SecureBlackbox product). Both products have WebDAV client components as well.