# webDAV on ASP.net web site

Tags: asp.net, webdav

I am hoping someone can offer me some direction in setting up webDAV on an ASP.net web site.

I have heard that webDAV will allow folder mappings through a web browser with webDAV.

Any tutorials or links, sample code etc would be greatly appreciated, I would like to learn all I can before diving further into this project.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following links might point you in the right direction

- [.Net WebDAV Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627705/net-webdav-server)
- http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/350/installing-and-configuring-webdav-on-iis/
- http://geekswithblogs.net/mnf/archive/2005/09/27/55089.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Here are couple of WebDAV server libraries that may save your time, comparing to creating WebDAV server from scratch:

- Free, open source library: http://sourceforge.net/projects/webdav/
- Payed, commercial license:  http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/